# Qual a diferença entre Classic e Integrated no Modo de Pipeline Gerenciado IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7

Estava com um problema na geração de um relatório Crystal Reports no qual foi resolvido quando alterei o Modo de Pipeline Gerenciado para Classic no Pool da Aplicação.

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre Classic e Integrated no Modo de Pipeline Gerenciado  no IIS7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O modo clássico (o único modo no IIS6 e versões mais antigas) é um modo onde o IIS só funciona com extensões *ISAPI* e filtros *ISAPI* diretamente. Grosso modo, o ASP.NET é apenas uma extensão *ISAPI* (`aspnet_isapi.dll`) e um filtro ISAPI (`aspnet_filter.dll`). O IIS apenas trata o ASP.NET como um plugin externo implementado no padrão *ISAPI* e trabalha com ele, como uma caixa preta (e só quando é preciso enviar a requisição para o ASP.NET). Neste modo, o ASP.NET não é muito diferente do PHP ou outras tecnologias para o IIS, como o ASP Clássico. Obviamente é mais limitado em uma série de coisas, sendo desencorajado de usar se a aplicação estiver em um Framework acima do 2.0.

Já o modo integrado é um novo modo que apareceu justamente no IIS7, onde o *pipeline* IIS é totalmente integrado com o canal de requisição ASP.NET. O ASP.NET pode ver cada pedido como quiser e manipular suas partes ao longo do caminho, não sendo mais tratado como um plugin externo. Neste modo, o ASP.NET é basicamente uma parte do IIS.

As opções são mantidas até hoje por mero esquema de compatibilidade, em que empresas não querem modificar seus sistemas mas desejam migrar de plataforma Windows, por exemplo. Fora isso, não há vantagem em utilizar o modo clássico.

Comment: Cigano, e para aplicações em ASP, existe algum problema em utilizar o modo integrado? Ou se há algum benefício em utilizar o modo clássico com ASP?

Comment: Problema eu acredito que não, assim como não há nenhuma vantagem. Só vale a pena se preocupar com esses modos pra DLLs do .NET mais antigo, onde isso era pertinente.